# Integral identity for moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the following identity for a random variable $X$ with mean $0$:

$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = 1+ \int_0^1 (1-y)\, \mathbb{E}\left[\, (tX)^2 e^{ytX} \right] dy$

I've encountered it in the proof of theorem 3.1 of [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/36788/subgaussians.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/36788/subgaussians.pdf)

Can someone please help me understand why it is true?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(1-y)\, \mathbb{E}\left[\, (tX)^2 e^{ytX}\right]\ge 0$ a.s, you can use Tonelli's theorem to switch the integral with expected value:
$$
\int_0^1 (1-y)\, \mathbb{E}\left[\, (tX)^2 e^{ytX} \right] dy=\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^1 (1-y)\, \, (tX)^2 e^{ytX}  dy\right]
$$
Then, treat $X$ like a constant, and evaluate that integral, then the rest is easy.

Answer (score 2):

We'll integrate twice by parts, viz.$$\int_0^1f(y)\partial_y^2g(y)dy=[f\partial_yg-f^\prime g]_0^1+\int_0^1f^{\prime\prime}gdy.$$Let $M_X(t):=\Bbb E[e^{tX}]$ so your integral is$$\begin{align}\int_0^1(1-y)\partial_y^2M_X(yt)dy&=[(1-y)\partial_yM_X(yt)+M_X(yt)]_0^1\\&=-\left.\partial_yM_X(yt)\right|_{y=0}+M_X(t)-1.\end{align}$$Since $\Bbb E[X]=0$, $\left.\partial_yM_X(yt)\right|_{y=0}=0$. Now rearrange.